# SQL - Counting re-occuring records based on date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `LoginTable` with just 2 columns: `id` as VarChar and `login_date` as Date. Here is a small sample:

```
+-------+------------+
| id    | login_date |
+-------+------------+
| user1 | 2014-10-15 |
| user1 | 2014-10-15 |
| user2 | 2014-10-15 |
| user3 | 2014-10-15 |
| user1 | 2014-10-16 |
| user3 | 2014-10-16 |
| user4 | 2014-10-16 |
| user2 | 2014-10-17 |
| user4 | 2014-10-17 |
+-------+------------+
```

I would like to write a SQL query that shows, for each day, how many users logged in the next day. For instance, Oct 15th has 3 unique logins - out of those 3, only 2 users have logged in on Oct 16th. THe output should be this:

```
+------------+--------------+
| Date       | NextDayLogin |
+------------+--------------+
| 2014-10-15 | 2            |
| 2014-10-16 | 1            |
| 2014-10-17 | 0            |
+------------+--------------+
```

My best try (theoretically) was this:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(id),
    DATE(login_date) as 'Dates' 
FROM LoginTable t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT(id) as id2, 
        DATE(login_date) as 'DatesNew' 
    FROM LoginTable 
    WHERE 'DatesNew' = DATE(t1.login_date) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
) t2
ON DATE(t1.login_date) = t2.DatesNew 
AND t1.id = t2.id2
```

However, I receive an error: `Unknown column t1.log_date in where clause` .
How can this be achieved? I am using MySQL if this matters.

Comment: as per the explanation, the result for `2014-10-16` should be `1`?

Comment: vkp - correct, thanks for pointing that out. I amended the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `left join` on the table with the specified +1 date to get the desired count.

[Fiddle with sample data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9fb35/15)

```
select t1.login_date, count(distinct t2.id) as nextdaylogin
from t t1
left join t t2 on t1.login_date = t2.login_date-1 and t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.login_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Just setup a new column maybe called `consecutive_days`

Then each time the users login, just test the `curr_date` against a `last_login_datetime` (column you can create as well) and if the times are less than 24 hours apart, set `consecutive_days = consecutive_days +1;`

If not the set it equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use a correlated subquery:

```
select date(login_date), count(*) as NumOnDay,
       (select count(*)
        from LoginTable lt2
        where lt2.login_date >= date_add(date(lt.login_date), interval 1 day) and
              lt2.login_date < date_add(date(lt.login_date), interval 2 day)
       ) as NumNextDay
from LoginTable lt
group by date(login_date)
order by date(login_date);
```

Your attempt doesn't even have a `count()`, so I'm not sure how you were thinking of getting the counts.

Comment: Running this doesn't produce the expected output. For ` 2014-10-15` column ` NumNextDay` has value 4 - it should be 2.

Comment: @BogdanC . . . It should have been the same as `NumOnDay`.  Off-by-one error, fixed now.